# ios 7 uinavigationbar uibarbuttonitem offset from edge

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Does anyone have a clue what is the actual distance from the screen's left edge to the back button of the `UINavigationBar` ?

Because I know that we cannot change in anyway the coordinates of it, so we can only use some other workarounds to mimic that if we need to offset the button with more / less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button itself has absolutely no padding or space between the left edge of the navigation bar and itself. Meaning you can tap at the very first pixel of the bar, and it will "touch" the back button.

If you mean how far it is from the left edge of the navigation bar to the beginning of the back button's image. Then exactly 16px on a retina display.

But that means you would reference the gap as 8px in your code, since iOS will automatically scale up on an @2x display.

(All these values were found from using the iOS simulator and Pixie.app.

Comment: I know that it does not, if it would, the touch area would be bigger. But that is what I meant to ask, just that I phrased it wrong. So if it 16 on a retina display, does that me the real amount of pixels 8 ? For instance the actual screen width of an iphone 5 with ios 7 is 320px, but the device resolution is 640 in width. So are we talking 16px as in resolution ?

Comment: @rolandjitsu, Right. You would reference such a gap in your code as 8px, since iOS will scale it up. Updated my answer.

Comment: @rolandjitsu The actual width in an iPhone 5 device is 640 pixels, but 320 **points**. Do not confuse the two.

Comment: @LeoNatan ~ true, should not confuse the two, my bad